# This jQuery is not working with Firefox only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox

I'm using it for megamenu. It's working fine on Google Chrome, Edge, Brave, and Opera.

It's not working on Firefox only.

**I have also put this jQuery between `<head>` tag. Still, not working.**

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";
    // Mega menu (with tabs)
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.megamenu-tabs').each(function(){
            $( '.menu-item', this ).wrapAll( '<ul class="tabs-nav" />');
            $( '.tab-content', this ).wrapAll( '<ul class="tabs-content-wrapper" />');
            $( '.tabs-nav, .tabs-content-wrapper', this ).wrapAll( '<li class="submenu-content" />');
            $('ul.sub-menu', this).show();
            
            $('.tab-content:not(:first-child)', this).addClass('tab-hidden');
            $('.tabs-nav li:first-child', this).addClass('nav-active');
            $('.tabs-nav li', this).hover(function() {
                var tabId = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).closest('.tabs-nav').find('li').removeClass('nav-active');
                $(this).addClass('nav-active');
                $(this).closest('.submenu-content').find('li.tab-content').addClass('tab-hidden');
                $(this).closest('.submenu-content').find('li.'+tabId).removeClass('tab-hidden');
            }); 
            
            var highestTab = $('.tabs-content-wrapper', this).outerHeight(); 
            $('.tabs-nav', this).css( 'min-height', highestTab-40 );
            
        });     
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add this as a [mcve] including the HTML using the snippet `[<>]` functionality in the edit menu? It would make it easier to debug.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, it's on WordPress. So, I don't know the file location of HTML code. It seems dynamic. Hence, all I have is that JS file.

Comment: It could be a problem with Mega Menu. If the jQuery code is working on every browser except FF I (just a guess) reckon the bug is elsewhere.

Comment: 'I don't know the file location of HTML code.' Right click, View Source, copy + paste

Comment: @Andy Nope. I'm sure it's the developer's mistake. But the company has shut down to work on that theme. Hence, they're not supported even after purchasing premium support. This issue is coming from the 2 years. I was expecting they will resolve it in the next update, but they didn't. Hence, I took my weapon (Stack Overflow). LOL

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan to: [link](http://mnkythemes.com/bitz/home/) ---- "Lifestyle" menu --- Select any link from that dropdown menu. Scroll your mouse on "Lifestyle", It will not work.

Comment: It maybe an addon interfering with the functionality. When I ran FF in troubleshoot mode so that none of my addons were loaded the site worked as you described. @ChinmayRajyaguru

Comment: @Andy I have tried this in troubleshooting mode now. It's not working for me. What can I do now? :(